# Logical operators with lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I have a problem:
I have two lists

```
Pipe_sizes = [15,15,22,15,32,45]
Flow_rate = [0.1,0.3,1,2,0.4,1.5]
```

I would like to use logical operators to change the list Pipe_size like:

```
if Flow_rate <= 0.2 then the pipe size is 15
if Flow_rate > 0.2 and <= 1 then the pipe size is 22
if Flow_rate > 1 and <=1.9  then the pipe size is 32
if Flow_rate > 1.9 then the pipe size is 45
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the list `Pipe_size`"? Do you mean select a value from the `Pipe_sizes`?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me where your rules are coming from. E.g. where does the > 1.9 = 45 come from? Why 1.9?

Comment: You want to do this with two lists and `bisect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pipe_sizes` is completely irrelevant for generating the ouput because all possible flow rate / pipe size combinations are covered in the list of conditions. So you can generate the result directly:

```
def flow_rate_to_size(rate):
    if rate <= 0.2:
        size = 15
    elif 0.2 < rate <= 1:
        size = 22
    elif 1 < rate <= 1.9:
        size = 32
    else:
        size = 45
    return size

flow_rates = [0.1, 0.3, 1, 2, 0.4, 1.5]
pipe_sizes = [flow_rate_to_size(rate) for rate in flow_rates]
print(pipe_sizes)
```

Output:

```
[15, 22, 22, 45, 22, 32]
```

Comment: This is the solution that came to my mind too, if you prefer you can use map at the very end `pipe_sizes = map(flow_rate_to_size, flow_rates)`

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate over the values of Flow_rate and update Pipe_sizes accordingly as follows:

```
Pipe_sizes = [15,15,22,15,32,45]
Flow_rate = [0.1,0.3,1,2,0.4,1.5]
for i, flow_rate in enumerate(Flow_rate):
    if flow_rate <= .2:
        Pipe_sizes[i] = 15
    elif flow_rate <= 1:
        Pipe_sizes[i] = 22
    elif flow_rate <= 1.9:
        Pipe_sizes[i] = 32
    else:
        Pipe_sizes[i] = 45
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a method to help you calculate the pipe sizes:

```
Flow_rate = [0.1,0.3,1,2,0.4,1.5]

def calculate_pipe_size(flow_rate):
    pipe_sizes = []
    for number in flow_rate:
        if number <= 0.2:
            pipe_sizes.append(15)
        if number > 0.2:
            pipe_sizes.append(22)
        if number > 1:
            pipe_sizes.append(32)
        if number > 1.9:
            pipe_sizes.append(45)
    return pipe_sizes

print calculate_pipe_size(Flow_rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Flow_rate = numpy.array([0.1,0.3,1,2,0.4,1.5])
pipe_sizes = numpy.zeros(len(FlowRate))

Flow_rate[Flow_rate <= 0.2] = 15
Flow_rate[Flow_rate > 0.2 & Flow_rate <= 0.4] = 15
...
```

might be good ... of coarse this isnt going to be very fast since each boolean iterates the whole list but it is fairly readable ...

Answer (score 0):

in golang, just because I need the practice (and hopefully to show off how much more concise python is....)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func getPipeSize(flowRate float32) (pipeSize int) {
    switch {
    case flowRate <= 0.2:
        pipeSize = 15
    case 0.2 < flowRate && flowRate <= 1.0:
        pipeSize = 22
    case 1.0 < flowRate && flowRate <= 1.9:
        pipeSize = 32
    case 1.9 < flowRate:
        pipeSize = 45
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    flow_rates := []float32{0.1, 0.3, 1, 2, 0.4, 1.5}
    pipe_sizes := make([]int, len(flow_rates))
    for i, flow_rate := range flow_rates {
        pipe_sizes[i] = getPipeSize(flow_rate)
    }
    fmt.Println(flow_rates)
    fmt.Println(pipe_sizes)
}
```

In Python:

```
def get_pipe_size(flow_rate):
    if flow_rate <= 0.2:
        pipe_size = 15
    elif 0.2 < flow_rate <= 1:
        pipe_size = 22
    elif 1 < flow_rate <= 1.9:
        pipe_size = 32
    else:
        pipe_size = 45
    return pipe_size

flow_rates = [0.1, 0.3, 1, 2, 0.4, 1.5]
pipe_sizes = [get_pipe_size(flow_rate) for flow_rate in flow_rates]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind modifying the inputs slightly `numpy` has some ways to bucket values like how you want:

```
import numpy as np
# pipe sizes for each of the different bins
pipe_bins = [15, 22, 32, 45]

# create the bins as monotonically increasing values 
# Each index i returned is such that 
# bins[i-1] <= x < bins[i] if bins is monotonically increasing
# I've changed to .000001 because you wanted x < 2
bins = np.array([0.200000001, 1.000000001, 1.9000000001])


input_flows = [0.1, 0.3, 1, 2, 0.4, 1.9]
# below list will contain the bins of each input flow
flow_in_bins = np.digitize(l, bins)
# now we can just map the flow bin to actual pipe size
result = map(lambda x: pipes[x], flow_in_bins)
print result
# result = [15, 22, 22, 45, 22, 45]
```

For more details about digitize check out the doc [numpy.digitize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)